# Lifecycle between activity and fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

In my debugging, I notice that onPause/onStart/onStop/onDestroy is called first on the fragment then on its activity, whereas onResume is the opposite - activity's onResume is called first before its fragment.

Why is the order different for onPause/onStart/onStop vs onResume between activity and fragment?

```
09-28 15:26:40.869  30320-30320/testintent D/TestFragment﹕ onStart
09-28 15:26:40.869  30320-30320/testintent D/TestActivity﹕ onStart 
09-28 15:26:40.869  30320-30320/testintent D/TestActivity﹕ onResume 
09-28 15:26:40.869  30320-30320/testintent D/TestFragment﹕ onResume 
09-28 15:26:40.869  30320-30320/testintent D/TestActivity﹕ onPostResume
```

Comment: are you sure for onStart?

Comment: @SatelliteSD Log included.

Comment: Interesting question. You see lots of diagrams of the Activity and Fragment life cycles running parallel to one another, but I can't find a diagram pointing directly from Activity's `onResume()` to Fragment's `onResume()`. Of Fragment's `onResume()`, the developer guide says, "This is generally tied to `Activity.onResume` of the containing Activity's lifecycle," but it doesn't specify how nor say when there might be an exception to the general case. Out of curiosity, are your `Log.d` statements the very first lines of each method?

Comment: Can you include your Java code? I'm curious about your `Log.d` statements and also your `super` calls. Having the code might make things more clear.

Answer (score -1):

*just guessing* when stopping, you stop from inner to outer components, whereas starting you start from outer to inner.

Comment: hm wait. I got you wrong. It doesn't match onStart. But I am convinced that my thinking is not that far off.

Answer (score -1):

Why is the onResume() order important in your activity/fragment?
According to Google guidelines Fragments should be designed as pluggable components without dependency on parent Activity.

I suspect that you may have too much dependency on your parent activity inside Fragment and may have to refactor.

Ideally Fragments should be designed in such a way that you'll be able to plug it into any activity without any modifications..